# OnClick event on disappearing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nGpmP/

When you click on that input, the button on the right appears. This button has `onclick();` event. The problem is, that this event is not firing up, since, when you click on a button, it disappears (and input is loosing focus), and javascript is not being fired up. How can I do it, so that this javascript will be executed?

Comment: Live examples are useful, but questions on Stackoverflow should be complete by themselves. 
See also: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Quentin: SO should just buy jsfiddle and integrate it. Everyone uses it anyways in here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.buttonInput input:not(:focus) ~ .buttonIcon {
    display: none;
}
```

becomes

```
.buttonInput .buttonIcon {
    display: none;
}
```

and

```
.buttonInput input:active ~ .buttonIcon {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

becomes

```
.buttonInput .buttonIcon:active {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

this way the button does not disappear until you clicked it.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uFVS/1/

Answer (score 3):

Use the mousedown event on the 'button' since the click is fired too late.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.buttonIcon', function () {
   $(this).prev('input').val('');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nGpmP/16/)**

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, but I wanted to only use `onclick();` this time... http://i.imgur.com/2gHIc1J.png 
Anyways thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use CSS focus selectors to hide/show the button, but rather hide the button using JavaScript's onBlur. Using the event object which is given as first argument to the onBlur method, you can check if the "target" attribute is the button - if yes, clear the node. 
Alternatively, you can use setTimout() with a low value such as 50 before hiding the button, thus allowing the click to fire before the button is hidden.

Comment: The problem is that I want to use as little of js as possible... :) But thanks for input!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes to your jsfeedle. Added some ID's and 2 jquery functions

```
<div class="buttonInput">
    <input id="inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Status..."/> 
    <div id="clearBtn" class="buttonIcon" onclick="ClearInput(this);">BTN</div> 
</div>
<script>
    $('#inputbox').click(function(){
        $('.buttonIcon').css('display','block');
    });

    $('#clearBtn').click(function(){
        $('#inputbox').val(' ');
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qpd6V/